# Software offloading (for routing/nat) in Linux distributions other than OpenWrt

Tags: networking

In OpenWrt, there is a feature called "software offloading" that can quite decently increase routing/nat throughput for OpenWrt-compatible WIFI routers.

If I install a non-OpenWrt distro like Raspberry Pi OS or Archlinuxarm on a RPI, what should I do to achieve that "software offloading" feature in OpenWrt? Thanks!

Comment: check this documentation: https://www.mind.be/openwrtsummit18/2018-10-29-OpenWRT18-network-offloading.html , https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_flowtable.rst